# add function in List/Set shows boolean value

Tags: java, list, set, addition

I want to add values into a Set which is a value in Map.
ie. `Map <String,HashSet<String>>` ..
my code is :

```
fieldMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

    if(fieldMap.get(qName)!=null){
                                    HashSet<String> tempSet = fieldMap.get(qName);
                                    tempSet.add(//String);
                                    fieldMap.put(qName, tempSet);}
```

here I wanted to put values directly like :
`fieldMap.put(qName,fieldMap.get(qName).add(//String))` .. So i can replace the above 3 lines in the loop.
But when I give '`add`' function ,  error message is coming like: "`The method put(String, HashSet<String>)` in the type `HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, boolean)`" .
Can anyone explain why this error is coming .. Also do we have to perform this by step by step only?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Set.add` returns a boolean, not the set. The boolean return value tells you if the value was added to the set. So you're trying to add a boolean as a value to the map.

However there is no need to keep adding the set back into the map. You can just get the set and add the new value to it:

```
if (fieldMap.containsKey(qName))
    fieldMap.get(qName).add(value);
```

Comment: fieldMap.get(qName).add(value); this line only showing the above specified error

Comment: Sorry that's not possible. The error is "The method put(String, HashSet) in the type HashMap> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)". There is no 'put' method in the statement I supplied so it cannot possibly give that error.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the new Java 8 method in `Map<K,V>` is specifically designed for:

```
V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)
```

In your case

```
fieldMap.computeIfAbsent(qName, k->new HashSet<>()).add(someString);
```

`computeIfAbsent` checks for the existence of `qName`. If it does not exist the "mapping function" (`new HashSet<>()`) is called and the result added to the `Map`. Then the value (either the existing one or the newly added one) is returned, and you finish by invoking `add()` on the `HashSet`.